# Where are all Mac App Store related preferences files located?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I want to check if automatic updates is available for Mac App Store. So I looked the content of `com.apple.appstore.plist` and `com.apple.storeagent.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences`. The first one didn't seems to has any information about what I wanted. The second seems to. So I store a copy of it. Go to `System Preferences > App Store` and disable "`Automatically check for updates`". Then I compared the "new" `com.apple.storeagent.plist` to the "old" one. No changes where made. So this information should be stored in somewhere else. Also tried to check the modified files during the action, so I used:

```
sudo fs_usage -w | grep "System Pref" | grep plist | grep -v "Info\.plist"
```

while doing the described action, but it doesn't show anything while I'm changing the "`Automatically check for updates`".
Does anybody can help me in this issue?
Thanks in advance.
Obs: I'm using OSX Mavericks 10.9.2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://askdifferent.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences seems to be in:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
```

I've solved the problem, using:

```
sudo fs_usage -w
```

(without the greps)
I put the previous command output to a log file and in this way I perceived that the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` was modified when I checked and unchecked `"Automatically check for updates"` in `System Preferences`. Than I opened it and saw the Key `"AutmoaticCheckEnabled"` that was exactly what I wanted.
So what solve my problem in this used the command described and check for the exact click moment.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "App Store" in System Preferences in OS X 10.8.5, there is an "Software Update" preference which is the App Store's.